# Executing shell script from java code and check if execution has passed

Tags: java, shell, unix

I am using below command to execute a shell script from java. I also need to check if script execution is successful without any errors. Is there any possible method to do this? Please advise.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.sh", arg1, arg2);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Thank you :) somehow it did not come up in the suggestions while typing question. Let me try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the process terminated which you can do with `Process.waitFor()` which blocks until the process completed. The return value of this call is the return code of the system command you invoked.

Comment: Thank you. can i use p.waitfor() followed by getting p.exitvalue() and checking if it is zero?

Comment: p.waitFor() returns the exit code, you can check that for zero: `p.waitFor() == 0` -> success

Answer (score 1):

To handle asynchronously, attach a threaded listener to `Process.getErrorStream` (ie listen to the read() method). When the process closes, you will get an IOException, releasing the thread. Then call `Process.exitValue()`. If you got anything coming off of the error stream or Process.exitValue() is not == 0, then that hints to probable failure

Comment: Thank you..will try this...